# How do I sell beer in a New Game+?

Tags: fiz

I beat Fiz! Hooray! Time to double back with a New Game + and take on the pesky challenges that I missed!

Only one problem. I've started a new game, made my first batch of beer... And there's nowhere for me to sell it:

[image: No markets]

I can do research on this non-market (apparently it's My Bodega and they like Lager), but there's no button to sell my beer there. Nor, for that matter, are there any other markets - even though my first batch was of such high quality that I got a bunch of alerts about how I'd unlocked a stack of new marketplaces. I also tried waiting until I ran out of money paying salaries, and restarting with a fresh New Game+ multiple times with no luck.

What gives? How can I sell my delicious, delicious beer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is apparently a [known issue.](https://bitbybitstudios.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/174823-new-game-ingredients-and-or-marketplaces-are-missing-from-their-menus) it can be resolved by force-quitting/relaunching the game.

To do this on iOS, while running Fiz, hold down the sleep/wake switch on your device until the "slide to power off" dialog appears, then release it and hold down the home button. The app will exit, and when you relaunch it, the missing lists should display properly.

Comment: For Android users, they'll want to force-stop the application through the Settings -> Applications menu to correct this behavior. (Had the same issue)